# how to update a specific item (cardview) in recyclerview OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I have a Fragment inside MainActivty, and inside this Fragment RecyclerView of Articles with cardView (inside this card i have like button and like counter) and when the user click on the cardView will open DetailsActivity that

and I want when onBackPressed to update just this item depends on the data changed (like button and like counter) in DetailsActivity

how to update just this Item ?

sorry for bad English!

Comment: Please attach your code, So that we can make appropriate changes.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged%28int%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First update the data of that specific position item of adapter.

After that call [notifyItemChanged(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) to update that specific `CardView` of `RecyclerView`

Notify any registered observers that the item at `position` has changed. Equivalent to calling `notifyItemChanged(position, null);`

This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any reflection of the data at `position` is out of date and should be updated. The item at `position` retains the same identity.

Comment: Ok i sent back (via OnBackPressed) a position and the object model of this item from DetailsActivity to MainActivity (that holds a Fragment that holds a RecyclerView). and received it (via OnActivityResult) in MainActivity.
the question here is how to send this position and object model from MainActivity to the fragment to perform notifyItemChanged(position, payload)

Comment: Create one method in fragment for update item and call it from `MainActivity` when you received in `OnActivityResult`

Comment: i added this method in fragment and i called it from MainAnctivity
public void updateItem(int position) {
        if (myAdapter != null) {
            myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    }
and I get myAdapter null !!

Comment: Post your full code in question. So, I can correct it.

Comment: @Priyank Patel So I have a Recycler. list of CardViews from a user entering data on a UI form.  A click on a CardView brings the user to a single CardView Activity to show that CardView's details.  A click on that CardView launches an Edit Activity so user can edit the original data.  How do I update the View for the single CardView Activity view when the user clicks "Save" button in my Edit Activity?  I use OnActivityResult() in CardView Activity with the Edit Activity so the user is returned to the single CardView Activity but the old View and data is showing.

Comment: @AJW you need to pass updated data in intent to `OnActivityResult()` from edit activity to single card view activity.

Comment: @Priyank Patel  I try that but it does not work.  Is that because the onCreate() in single CardView Activity gets item object and data from the MainActivity (the RecyclerView list)?

Comment: @AJW Can you create another question with your problem code? So that, I can understand your issue better and answer it.